# How to load symbol table to debug ios app with gdb?

Tags: ios, security, debugging, gdb

I'm trying to debug ios apps when its running by using gdb.

I get the process id of the app like this

```
  iPod:/Applications/AntiPiracyDemo.app root# ps ax | grep Anti
  808   ??  Ss     0:00.94 /Applications/AntiPiracyDemo.app/AntiPiracyDemo
  826 s001  R+     0:00.00 grep Anti
  iPod:/Applications/AntiPiracyDemo.app root#
```

Attaching the process to gdb and trying set a break point to the method called `isJailbroken`, as shown below.

```
iPod:/Applications/AntiPiracyDemo.app root# gdb -q -p 808
/private/var/stash/Applications/AntiPiracyDemo.app/808: No such file or directory
Attaching to process 808.
0x3b3f1eb4 in ?? ()
(gdb) b -[AntiPiracyViewController isJailbroken]
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) n
(gdb)
```

gdb is asking some question : `0x3b3f1eb4 in ??` , and also saying `No symbol table is loaded.`

Can anyone please tell me which file I need to attach and how can I do that ? (for gdb to load symbol table)

Thanks!

Comment: Can I ask why you aren't using Xcode and lldb?

Comment: I was actually trying to do the steps mentioned here.. http://hackoftheday.securitytube.net/2013/04/bypassing-jailbroken-checks-in-ios.html

Comment: I see the lldb is an alternative solution developed by Apple. Let me try using that.. Thanks!